# linker cannot find a package that is already installed

Tags: make, symbolic-link, openssl

I am trying to follow [instructions](https://docs.px4.io/master/en/dev_setup/fast-dds-installation.html) for installation of FAST-DDS on Ubuntu 18.04. During make -j$(nproc --all),I get this error

```
[  4%] Built target fastcdr
[  5%] Linking CXX shared library libfastrtps.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenSSL::SSL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenSSL::Crypto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/cpp/CMakeFiles/fastrtps.dir/build.make:4047: recipe for target 'src/cpp/libfastrtps.so.1.8.2' failed
make[2]: *** [src/cpp/libfastrtps.so.1.8.2] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1054: recipe for target 'src/cpp/CMakeFiles/fastrtps.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/cpp/CMakeFiles/fastrtps.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Openssl exists on my system, `OpenSSL 1.1.1 11 Sep 2018`, libssl-dev is also there,
`libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.9).`

how do i fix this problem?

here is the [/build/Makefile](http://sharetext.me/tcyloqfhym) and complete [terminal output](http://sharetext.me/dbhgkm9lmj)

Comment: Have tried to preciously follow https://fast-dds.docs.eprosima.com/en/latest/installation/sources/sources_linux.html ? Did you run `sudo apt install libssl-dev`?

Comment: This looks like an issue with the `cmake` step of the build - the strings `OpenSSL::SSL` and `OpenSSL::Crypto` should have been replaced with actual library names. See for example [FindOpenSSL](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/FindOpenSSL.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04 : No issues with the Git version of Fast-DDS. (My cmake version is 3.16.3 : `memory` requires cmake => 3.11)

```
sudo apt install libasio-dev libtinyxml2-dev 

git clone https://github.com/foonathan/memory.git
cd memory/ && mkdir build && cd build/
cmake .. && make && sudo make install
    
git clone https://github.com/eProsima/Fast-DDS.git
cd Fast-DDS/
git submodule update --init --recursive

cd thirdparty/fastcdr/ && mkdir build && cd build/
cmake .. && make && sudo make install && exit

cd Fast-DDS/ && mkdir build && cd build/
cmake ..
make                    ## No errors
[ 99%] Built target fastrtps
Scanning dependencies of target fast-discovery-server
[ 99%] Building CXX object tools/fds/CMakeFiles/fast-discovery-server.dir/server.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable fast-discovery-server-1.0.0
[100%] Built target fast-discovery-server
sudo make install        ## No errors
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was a make problem. had to update cmake and symbolically reference it